# Testing Core Bluetooth Applications in the iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a question about using BLE with the iOS Simulator.

I followed these instructions to set up XCode simulator with BLE: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2295/_index.html

I use a Mac os 11.6 big sur and Xcode 12.5 on VMware Machine with built-in BLE and a CSR USB BLE Dongle. Mac OS X discovers the USB Dongle, because it is shown in the System Information.

After that I enter this command:

sudo nvram bluetoothHostControllerSwitchBehavior="never"

to have the Broadcom chip again and Bluetooth configuration does not appear in the ios emulator settings app and is not available.

So what the problem here?

Thanks for help!

[Bluetooth info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rklVE.png),
[Simulator Setting App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWePO.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the problem is that technote is ancient.

BLE support was dropped from the simulator in iOS 7

You need to use a real device to debug Core Bluetooth iOS applications.

Core Bluetooth does have a consistent API between iOS and macOS so you may be able to trysome code in a Mac app and then transfer it to your iOS app, but for the final test you will need to use an iOS device.